# Height of a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have been trying to make a layout for my app, where I set the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

This is my code ::

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hp.money.DashBoard">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_amount_display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">
           .....
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/last_10_transaction" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/last_transactions_lv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am using a ListView inside a ScrollView, which is a bad idea, I know! It leads to some scrolling issues, I believe. But I have to dynamically update data on my screen during runtime, and I think only the listview can handle it. If there's any other `View` to do it, please suggest.

Now, the problem is that even if the Data source of the ListView has 10 items, the height of the ListView always remains equal to the size of one listView element, but the height of the listview is set to `wrap_content`, so probably it is supposed to resize accordingly. But it doesn't! How to fix this?

This is how it looks, even though the Listview has 10 items!
The ListView is the one which has a heading as LAST 10 TRANSACTIONS

[image: The ListView is the one which has a heading as LAST 10 TRANSACTIONS]

Why I used a ScrollView??

I put a scrollview, because, the number of enteries in the listview can be many, so I want that when the user scrolls to see the entries not currently visible int the listview, the whole page gets scrolled, and not only the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by " dynamically insert data into the Listview during runtime". If you are modifying list data dynamically then `ListView` can handle it internally. You no need to do anything in that case. So you can remove the `ScrollView` so it works fine.

Comment: Hi. What I meant by "dynamically inserting data" was that, as mentioned by others, I cannot have a listView inside a ScrollView, and even I have read about this before posting the question, what I meant was, that like listview manages the dynamically updated data, is there any other way that I can do that without using a listview, like dynamically handle data in a LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

You can not add a ListView inside ScrollView .
For considering your needs you can set ListView height dynamically to fulfill your needs ...
After setting up your list adapter simply call this method...

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Comment: after every `notifyDataSetChanged` I will again have to call this function right??

Comment: If im right, wrap_content will not work on a ListView the same as it will not work on a ScrollView, im sure its because how Android calc layout sizes before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed, you can't put a ListView inside a ScrollView (anyways it doesn't make sense, ListView has its own scroll)

> But I have to dynamically insert data into the Listview during runtime, if there's any other way to do it, please suggest.

I can't see why you think you can't, and want to know why you think a ScrollView will do it.

If you have created your own adapter to fill that ListView you should have something like this:

```
class listViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
     {
     }
     public int getCount()
     {
     }
     public Object getItem(int position) {
     }
     public long getItemId(int position){
     }
}
```

Then you should create a data field and a setter

```
private Arraylist<DataType> data;

public void setData(Arraylist<DataType> data)
{
    data = data;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
ListView lv = findViewById...
ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter();
adapter.setData(data);
lv.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter());
```

When you have added or deleted data you can reload it by calling

```
adapter.notifySetDataChanged();
```

Comment: Hi. I know I can add data into the ListView. I couldn't make myself clear in the question. I meant just like you said I cannot have a Listview in a ScrollView, my motive is to add a view, which can dynamically handle data being updated by the user, and I only see the listView to handle that for me. Further, I put a scrollview, because, the number of enteries in the listview can be many, so I want that when the user scrolls to see the entries not currently visible int the listview, the whole page gets scrolled, and not only the listview.

Comment: If i understand, you want to set explicit height size to the listView, based on content? if you do that, you will still have scrolling issues. Maybe your best bet is to just use the scrollView and manage to add/delete data from it dinamically.